# Unable to import Pandas Profiling

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-profiling

I am unable to import pandas profiling in jupyter notebook. Could someone please tell me whats wrong.
[image]

Comment: Did you install `pandas_profiling` using pip or conda? if so then mention that in the question also

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Conda

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks a lot to all who tried to help me out. This worked.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can install via pip but I like to use conda for as many installs as possible to help keep the environment easier to work with.

The conda page shows multiple versions for pandas-profiling: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas-profiling

You need to specify the latest one when installing:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=2.6.0
```

Replace 2.6.0 with the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac

```
pip install pandas-profiling
```

And For Ubuntu

```
!pip install pandas-profiling
```

Comment: The ! is not necessary for Ubuntu. Only if you're using any kind of jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Anaconda distribution then use this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pandas-profiling

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pandas-profiling
```

I was getting the same problem and it worked for me.

Comment: Here you provided three options, Which one should we use to install pandas-profiling?

Answer (score 2):

`conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling` Try this command to install 
If it doesn't work then try `pip install pandas-profiling`

Comment: user have already installed `pandas_profiling` so no reason to put it as answer

Comment: No, it is not installed @ArpitSolanki

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314314/unable-to-import-pandas-profiling/49314373?noredirect=1#comment85630081_49314314. OP said that he installed using conda

Comment: The link which you are referring is invalid @ArpitSolanki

Comment: How can it be invalid I just checked it. Its the link to the comment made by OP in the question, see that first

Comment: The anaconda channel has a much older version of pandas-profiling you don't want to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you run jupyter notebook so:

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

You can install the packages so:

```
python -m pip install pandas-profiling
```

I had a lot of trouble because the 'python' of the jupyter notebook when I ran only `jupyter notebook` was another installation of python than the one on my bash.
If you run the module 'jupyter notebook' and the module 'pip' with the commands 'python -m' before, you ensure that you are using the same installation.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple option to do so.

1. Go to CMD & then type python -m pip install pandas-profiling
2. Go to CMD & conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=2.6.0
3. import sys class in Jupyter note book & enter below line & enter
   !{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling
   Above is really cool to use.
4. Little manual but works most of the time. 
   Download pandas-profile lib from https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/#modal-close
   extract it and paste C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages
   Restart your Anaconda & happy to use.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's an issue with the version.
Try this

```
!pip install -U pandas-profiling
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run "pip install pandas-profiling" in Anaconda command prompt then import panadas_profiling, it will work

Answer (score 0):

you can run your anaconda prompt as administrator and do:
conda intall -c anaconda pandas-profiling

While running it may ask for updating the present libraries, do "y" for it.
After completion go to jupyter notebook and do "import pandas_profiling"

Hope it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!pip install pandas-profiling[notebook]
```