# How to load pandas_profiling into a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 on my Mac and verified that pandas-profiling 1.4.1 is in the anaconda3 environment. Then, I launched Jupyter Notebook from within Anaconda Navigator's anaconda3 environment.

However, when I run a python cell Jupyter Notebook does not import pandas_profiling, it fails to find pandas_profile module. What needs to be changed to get Jupyter Notebook to find the pandas-profiling module?

> ---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call

> last) Input In [1], in <cell line: 13>()
> 11 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
> 12 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
> ---> 13 import pandas_profiling
> 15 from matplotlib import rcParams
> 16 import warnings
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_profiling'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import Pandas Profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314314/unable-to-import-pandas-profiling)

Comment: I tried have a mac. I have Anaconda3. I tried pip install pandas-profiling and that failed with a pip's dependency resolver issue on anaconda-project 'ruamel-yaml' is not installed. Now, when I run 'jupyter notebook' command, it fails to start. Looks like I'm worse off than before. :(

Comment: Another way to get pandas-profiling in the above link.  (conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=3.2.0) fails at Conda's 'Solving environment' step.